# sequelize.import is not a function

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sequelize, ddd

Consulta chic@s, estoy obteniendo el error del titular, sequelize.import is not a function en mi archivo index de entities en esta linea `const model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));`

Es la primera vez en la que estoy trabajando con node y sequelize implementando Clean Architecture, no se muy bien por donde salirle.. lo cierto es que en el tutorial que sigo, esta linea de código funciona bien así como esta, en una versión anterior a la 6 de sequelize.

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Para aclararnos seria conveniente que incluyas mas información como las versiones que usas y un código de ejemplo en el contexto para que probemos

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que vayas directo a la documentación: [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html)

Tiene buenos ejemplos de como comenzar con ella, viendo los codigos de ejemplos debería quedarte un poco mas claro.

Ademas te sugiero que veas a futuro como hacer los joins de la [doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html) o de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460270/how-to-make-join-queries-using-sequelize-on-node-js)

Por ejemplo, puedes definir tu conexión de la siguiente manera

**Model.js**

```
import { Model, Sequelize } from 'sequelize'

export const sequelize = 
    new Sequelize(process.env.PGDB, process.env.PGUSER, process.env.PGPASSWORD, {
      dialect: 'postgres',
      dialectOptions: { ssl },
      host: process.env.PGHOST,
      port: process.env.PGPORT
    })
```

Luego definir una entidad o tabla usando la conexión antes definida.

**User.js**

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize'
import { sequelize } from '../Model'

export class User extends Model {}

User.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  },
  org: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'users'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que es un tema de version, en mi localHost me genera ese error, pero en mi VPS luego de instalar sequelize no genero el error